# Bulk Insert CSV File Using Format File

Tags: sql-server, file, csv, format, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert a CSV file into a SQL database using Bulk Insert and a Format File but I am having some trouble. I have been using the following tutorial.

http://www.bidn.com/blogs/marcoadf/bidn-blog/2479/bulk-insert-format-file-skip-column

When I run the script I get this error I think it has something to do with the format of the Format File.

```
Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2, column 3 (Ref).
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 3
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

**Table Format**

```
[Id]       INT           NULL,
[Name]     NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Townland] NVARCHAR (100) NULL,
[Ref]      INT           NULL,
[Lat]      FLOAT (53)    NULL,
[Lng]      FLOAT (53)    NULL
```

**TSQL**

```
use HOM
go
bulk insert HouseInfo
from 'c:\HOM\Houses_of_Mayo_02_02_2015.txt'
with
(
firstrow = 2,
fieldterminator = ',',
FORMATFILE = 'c:\HOM\Format_File.fmt'
)
select *
from HouseInfo
```

**Format File**

```
10.0
6
1   SQLINT      0   50  ","    2    Id          ""  
2   SQLNCHAR    0   50  ","    3    Name        ""
3   SQLNCHAR    0   100 ","    4    Townland    ""
4   SQLINT      0   50  ","    5    Ref         ""
5   SQLFLT8     0   53  ","    6    Lat         ""
6   SQLFLT8     0   53  "\n"   7    Lng         ""
```

**CSV File**

```
Id,Name,Townland,Ref,Lat,Lng
A1,Aasleagh Lodge,Srahatloe,1,53.613873,-9.668301
A2,Aasleagh Rectory,Srahatloe,2,53.612478,-9.668033
A3,Abbey Lodge,Carrowkeel (ED Croaghpatrick),3,53.785667,-9.638768
A4,Abbeytown House,Abbeytown,4,54.107701,-9.318194
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are few things which I noticed are wrong in your code above.

1. `Id` is an `INT` type however data in csv is `A1,A2...` for this column
2. In your format file, The database column ordering starts from 2 and not from 1.

You don't need a format file, you can use `fieldterminator = ',',rowterminator='\n'` directly without a format file.

```
bulk insert HouseInfo
from 'E:\bcp\Houses_of_Mayo_02_02_2015.txt'
with
(
    firstrow = 2,
    fieldterminator = ',',rowterminator='\n'
)
select *
from HouseInfo
```